# Should I cut the mud sill/top plates on a 16' wall 5.5" short to allow for the wall it butts into?

Tags: sheathing

I'm building a hangar (think garage). After I put one wall up (all will be of 2x6 studs), I'll be continuing with 16-foot mud sills/top plates for the perpendicular wall. Should I cut those 5.5" short so that when I stand that second wall up, the sheathing that overlaps the butt end of the first wall will line up on the studs of the 16-foot (second) wall?

In other words, if I just built the second wall the full 16 feet in length, that wall would be 16' 5.5" long (including the first wall it butts up against) and four 4x8 sheets of OSB either wouldn't overlap the corner or would fall 5.5" short of the end of the second wall.